# Python igraph: TypeError: iterable must return pairs of integers or strings

Tags: python, typeerror, igraph

I was wondering what is wring with this code:

```
import igraph as ig
test = ig.Graph()
test.add_vertices(0)
test.add_vertices(1)
test.add_vertices(2)
test.add_edges((1,2))`
```

When I run it, I receive the following error:

```
TypeError: iterable must return pairs of integers or strings
```

Comment: If you want to add *one* edge, why are you using `add_edges`, plural? `add_edges` expects a list (or other iterable) of edges, not just a single unwrapped edge.

Comment: Considering the particular way you're misusing `add_edges`, you might want to check whether you've understood `add_vertices` correctly. `test.add_vertices(0)` doesn't add a single vertex labeled 0 to the graph; it adds 0 vertices.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks. But in [igraph tutorial](http://www.cs.rhul.ac.uk/home/tamas/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html) it is mentioned that even for adding one edge, we should use `add_edges`

Comment: @msmazh -- you need to a _list length 1_ of edges!

Comment: Weird. The tutorial does indeed say that you should be able to `test.add_edges((1, 2))`, without wrapping it in a list (contrary to the `add_edges` documentation). Can you show the complete stack trace of the error?

Comment: Also, what igraph version are you on?

Comment: @Malvolio thanks. it worked

Comment: @user2357112 apparently that tutorial is wrong. I changed it to `add_edges([(1,2)])` and it worked.

Comment: @user2357112 -- "weird" that the tutorial is wrong?  "Unfortunate" but not "unusual".